# C# Akka multithreaded creating of actors

Tags: c#, multithreading, actor, akka.net, actorsystem

I created `singleton` wrapper over `ActorSystem`

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml.Linq;

using Akka.Actor;
using Akka.Configuration;

namespace AkkaPOC
{
    public sealed class ActorsDirector : IDisposable
    {    
        private static readonly Lazy<ActorsDirector> instance =
            new Lazy<ActorsDirector>(() =>
                new ActorsDirector(),
                LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

        public static ActorSystem Instance
            => instance.Value.director;

        private readonly ActorSystem director;

        private ActorsDirector()
        {
            var config  = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(
                XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@$"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\akka.config"))
                        .Descendants("hocon")
                        .Single()
                        .Value);

            this.director = ActorSystem.Create("ActorDirector", config);
        }

        bool isDisposed = false;

        ~ActorsDirector()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (this.isDisposed)
                return;
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.director.Dispose();
            }

            this.isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I use it from synchronously code all is fine!
But when `Actor`'s are created in parallel `Task`'s

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    new Task(() =>
    {
        var actor = ActorsDirector.Instance
                                    .ActorOf<AskerActor>()
                                    .Ask<T>(parameters)
        actor.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("uint: {0}", actor.Result);
    }).Start();
}
```

project stops in wrapper's ctor after

```cs
this.director = ActorSystem.Create("ActorDirector", config);
```

and doesn`t work further.

Which is interesting, if in the cycle we make a restriction not of 20, but not more than 8, then with some delay everything will work.

Can someone say me what I do incorrect and how to fix it.

Comment: Hello, i have noticed some problem in your code but i'm not quite sure that it's the problem. You don't have any static reference at actor system variable at global application level as it recommended by documentation. All your references are local inside lambda and after task completion GC can delete actor system object. Can you create reference at actor system at application root level and try again?

Comment: @SergeyPopov, I added `public static ActorSystem system = ActorsDirector.Instance;` above `Main`- nothing is changed

Comment: Ok, can you show me the full sources?